# Is there a way to force the state of on/off switch in 3-D world?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

In normal worlds, I can force a on/off state with a simple contraption like so:

> ----||SP|
> |OF|SH|

SP = sideways spring
OF = On/Off switch
SH = Shell with the color of the block I want to force on the square

This contraption works by immediately killing off the shell if the color I want is active, and triggering the on/off block then killing off the shell if its not.

Unfortunately, I can't do this in 3D world because red/blue switchable blocks do not exist, so is there another way to force the on/off state with a contraption?

I need to be able to specifically set it to on/off, not just a toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the answer by l I, you have a few options. Since on/off switches only interact with a couple of things including conveyor belts, the designs for this are going to be based off those, naturally.

Option 1: Activates instantly, but may be faulty from spawn order.

[image: Switchable conveyor belt with a switch and blaster on it with a bomb in between.]

Option 2: Does not activate instantly, but has a simple design and is very small. It will still work regardless of snow theme or not.

[image: Switch with a snowball on a sloped switchable conveyor leading up to it.]

Both designs are pretty compact, but option 2 also requires 1 less entity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Showsni for improving the design:

Using switchable conveyor belts, its possible to build a contraption that toggles a specific state like so:

> __________|L| 
>  |OF||BOMB|>>>>>>

OF = On/Off switch
BOMB = bomb
L = Launcher

">>>"= conveyor leading away from the switch, assuming I want the "on" state to be active, reverse direction if its the other case.

If the desired state is not active, the launcher will fall on the bomb and activate it immediately, if it is active, the conveyor will take the launcher away.  You can even block the launcher movement with a wall so it can activate if the on/off state ever changes.

Comment: Instead of having the bomb on the conveyor, you could have a launcher on the conveyor, then place the unlit bomb next to the switch in a one space gap immediately diagonally below, so either the launcher will drop on it and set it off or the launcher will go the other way and nothing will happen. Does that work? My Switch is at home so I can't test.

Comment: @Showsni that works much better, if you want to post it as an answer I will accept it, if you don't, I can just update my answer.